# How can I reattach a kitchen cabinet door hinge with plastic dowels?

Tags: doors, anchor

I was hoping that maybe someone could give me some recommendations what to do with my kitchen cupboard door. It came off after a washing machine next to it started "walking" during the spinning cycle and as it was so intense and there was no room for it to move, it broke the door. It is a heavy 5KG door and is fixed using these plastic dovels (see pics).

Anything I can do to repair this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think a similar question has been answered before but I can't find it at the moment.

1. Open that hinge and unscrew the metal screws that are now holding the plastic plugs to the hinge.
2. Use 2-part epoxy to attach the plastic plugs into the craters in the cupboard side. Take care to get them located in exactly right position and flush with the surface. If necessary make a jig using scrap wood. Use clamps or a jig to hold everything in position until set.
3. Level the feet on the washing machine (one or more will have a hexagonal nut you turn to raise or lower that foot)
4. Ensure you always load the machine so that it doesn't get out of balance. Some machines have that sort of problem with part loads. Check the manual.
5. Accept that despite all the above, the material and fixing method are too weak for the stress you are applying
6. Add two additional hinges to the two that currently support the door. You can buy those hinges and you can also buy installation kits that include the appropriate sized forstner bits and jigs to align and locate the holes properly.

Comment: I wonder how well the epoxy will adhere to the plastic plugs?

Answer (score -1):

Fill holes with bondo, redrill holes and reattach hinge.